# Webpack HTML bundling - how to remove white spaces and new lines?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

In my AngularJS project I have an HTML template in which the innerText is in a new line:

```
<button class="btn">
    Click here
</button>
```

I'm using webpack as my bundler. I want it to trim those new lines/white spaces. I tried the following configuration using HtmlWebpackPlugin + minify:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({names: ['vendor'], filename: 'js/[name].js'}),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body',
        minify: {
            collapseWhitespace: true
        }
    }),
```

But it doesn't work - the resulting HTML still has a new line.
The expected result is:

```
<button class="btn">Click here</button>
```

Any idea how to have those spaces removed?

Comment: Not sure about this, but another solution with no plugins is to use `>` and `<` signs right before the text, line whtiespace `>Click here<` whtiespace. It is commonly used in vue-cli webpack projects.

Answer (score -1):

```
**remove newlines**

/\r?\n|\r/g
let foo = 'bar\nbar';
foo = foo.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " "); /* replace all newlines with a space */
console.log(foo); 


**remove all whitespaces**
var spacesString= "Do I have spaces?"; 
var noSpacesString= myString.replace(/ /g,'');
```